# Firebase function deploys, but no logs produced & no response to trigger by onCreate() event

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Firebase Cloud Function that will listen for a new post on my react native app's feed, and then send notifications of the post to all users. I've decided to start small and first understand Firebase Cloud Functions on a basic level.

Following the firebase documentation for Realtime Database triggers, I've tried to create the function shown in the code below. I believe that the function is deploying to my database just fine because this is outputted on the command prompt:
[image: Command Prompt Output]

Also, my firebase project seems to receive and store the function too:
[image: Firebase Project Functions]
However, when I return to my database and create a new node at the specified path, nothing happens. Additionally, I check the 'logs' in the functions tab and nothing is there.

Any help would be appreciated...Thank you!

**EDIT 1**
This is a screencapture of my database:
[image]

**EDIT 2**
Tried including the admin SDK (as shown below) but no change.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/{organization}/posts/')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const post = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.organization, post);
      const uppercasePost = post.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('cloudFunctionTest').set(uppercasePost);
    });
```

Comment: Can you show a print screen of your database please?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec edited!

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Not OP, but I see that OP is not initializing the Admin SDK... and [step #3 of the Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) suggests the Admin SDK is necessary to access the DB... I could see that meaning it's necessary to read/write data separately... but could it mean it's necessary even for a DB trigger?

Comment: @JeremyW I have tried both with and without these steps but, unfortunately, no change. I will edit my code above to include these steps though

Comment: @RayhanMemon Were do you create a new node? I.e.what is "the specified path"?  Under "posts"? Under "organization"? Or under "organizations" (with an S)? You have to be very precise.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not creating a "post" under the correct path.

As a matter of fact, with your code

```
exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/{organization}/posts/')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {})
```

the Cloud Function will be triggered for any node like the following ones

```
ksigapp   // <- Root of your database
    - abcd  //<- This corresponds to {organization} in your code
        - posts: "lowercase"
    - efgh  // <- This corresponds to {organization} in your code
        - posts: "whatever"
    - IUUY7676676fgfgfg7  //<- This corresponds to {organization} in your code
        - posts: "lowercase2"

....
```

and, secondly, the value of the `posts` must be a string and cannot be an object because `post.toUpperCase();` will generate an error (you cannot apply this method to an object).

In other words, the following will generate an error:

```
ksigapp   // <- Root of your database
    - abcd  
        - posts
           - postId
              - author: "John"
              - subject: "Lorem ipsus"
```

So you most probably have to reconsider your Cloud Function path

You may study the following official Firebase examples: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master#rtdb